# Does a basic CSS file to produce acceptable documents exist anywhere?

Tags: epub, css

I am currently writing a processor to convert a specific website to EPUB and everything works fine except that the result I get, when read in Calibre does not look very nice I think.

I was looking for a CSS file to beautify the result but so far I have not been ale to is this thread [Any opensource or free css stylesheets for books?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6742/any-opensource-or-free-css-stylesheets-for-books) but it dates back to 2016 and I was wondering if there was something more generic / up-to-date that could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the [Blitz general purpose stylesheet](https://github.com/FriendsOfEpub/Blitz).

Comment: Thanks Nemo XXX, I had not found this, will give it a try, seems the best option for the moment.